# How to fix an issue when window in undefined in tauri?

Tags: javascript, tauri

I am new at tauri and I have faced the issue with getting data from @tauri-apps/api.

```
"@tauri-apps/api": "^1.1.0",
"@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.1.1"
```

This is my React code below:

```
/index.jsx

import {getTauriVersion} from "@tauri-apps/api/app"
function App() {
   const func = async () => {
       const res = await getTauriVersion()
       return res    
   }
   return (<></>)
}
```

This is my tauri.conf.json

```
{
   "build": {
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:1420",
    "distDir": "../dist",
    "withGlobalTauri": true
  },
  ...
  "tauri": {
     "allowList": {"all": true}
  }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.__TAURI_IPC__ is not a function
unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: window is not defined
at o (file:///C:/test/test/node_modules/@tauri-apps/api/tauri- 
a4b3335a.js:1:100)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical 2 sources for this kind of error are:

1. you're in a SSR environment - This could be a problem with next.js for example, but not with plain React.
2. you're viewing the frontend in your browser - Tauri's APIs are only injected into actual Tauri windows.

Comment: I guess the solution is just not to use Next.JS for Tauri? I'll try using ViteJS instead.

Comment: @C.Tale That would probably be the easiest solution, but it's not necessary per se. You just need to be careful because some nextjs features don't work when you use `next export` and you need to use dynamic imports for the window and path modules to make sure they are only imported on the client-side, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like if you import anything from the root package of `@tauri-apps/api`, it seems like it tries to access the global `window` instance before the window initializes (?), which is undefined.

My problem was to use `invoke` to request some data from Rust side. [FabianLars's answer](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/7488#issuecomment-1749157693) on Github helped me. Basically, whenever you want to import something from `@tauri-apps/api`, just import it from a submodule.

```js
// instead of this
import { invoke } from "@tauri-apps/api";

// do this
import { invoke } from "@tauri-apps/api/tauri";
```

Comment: This one helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to judge

```
const handleIsTauri = () => {
    return Boolean(
  typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window !== undefined &&
  window.__TAURI_IPC__ !== undefined
)};
```